# postfix running but not accessible

Tags: postfix

I've got postfix running (or so it seems) on my Debian 10 system:

```
user@leah ~ # service postfix status
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2020-01-04 10:41:52 CET; 5min ago
  Process: 24700 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24700 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Jan 04 10:41:52 leah.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Jan 04 10:41:52 leah.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

But it appears not to be:

```
user@leah ~ # telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

postfix is setup to listen to localhost only, since it is supposed to only send out emails of jenkins.

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
```

I can send emails using the mail command:

```
echo "It works" | mail -s "Does it work?" myemail@mydomain.org
```

It seems port 25 is open

```
user@leah ~ # netstat -pln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1502/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44789         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1502/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1176/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6665/postgres
tcp      101      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1609/master
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      10419/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1685/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::8082                 :::*                    LISTEN      1336/java
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      2021/proftpd: (acce
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1176/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      6665/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::42361                :::*                    LISTEN      1336/java
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1609/master
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      10419/java
udp        0      0 172.9.25.211:123        0.0.0.0:*                           1147/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           1147/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           1147/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                           1146/minissdpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           698/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39980           0.0.0.0:*                           698/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 fe90::6e62:6dff:fec:123 :::*                                1147/ntpd
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                1147/ntpd
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                1147/ntpd
udp6       0      0 :::33848                :::*                                1336/java
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                1336/java
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                698/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::41184                :::*                                698/avahi-daemon: r
```

And postfix is listening on that port (process 1609):

```
user@leah ~ # ps -ef | grep 1609
root      1609     1  0 Jan02 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/master -w
```

Why is postfix not accessible on port 25?

Comment: Does your firewall allow traffic on localhost?

Comment: Tomcat can access postgres on locahost:5432, so I'd say yes.

Answer (score 0):

What firewall are you running? If you are running IPtables, try running this command, which will make "accept all loopback traffic" your first rule in iptables.:

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -t filter -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Another possible issue is that you are using IPv6 and your firewall is only an IPv4 firewall. Try running this command, which will only use telnet over IPv4, not IPv6. :

```
telnet -4 localhost 25
```

Also, try using 127.0.0.1, not localhost, as localhost requires DNS resolution:

```
telnet -4 127.0.0.1 25
```

Another issue I see is the Recv-Q column for Postfix's process running on port 25. It says 101 bytes have been received by the kernel, but Postfix hasn't asked for them yet. Here's an article that explains that issue more in-depth:

> https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6537582
>
> High Recv-Q means the data is put on TCP/IP receive buffer, but the application does not call recv() to copy it from TCP/IP buffer to the application buffer.

Maybe you should make sure that Postifx isn't limiting the maximum number of connections. In other words, your problem might be on the application layer. There's two things you should do. Tune the values as you find fit for your use case:

1. In main.cf:

   smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 50
2. In master.cf:

> https://serverfault.com/questions/658156/limit-concurrent-connections-to-postfix-server
>
> If you want to change the maximal number of smtpd running you should make your changes in /etc/postfix/master.cf. You change - to 50 in the 7th column then restart postfix with postfix restart (or a distro specific substitute).
>
> smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       50      smtpd

The final thing I could think of is that maybe your problem is TLS related. Try running:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect 127.0.0.1:25
```

If you are still having issues, try disabling TLS altogether on port 25 in Postfix and see if you can connect.

I really hope this helps!!